# One time pass a data to Soap service that remain available

Tags: java, web-services, soap, architecture, client-server

We have a web application that is using client service model. We are using SOAP Client and Soap Service.
Technology and architecture of current application -
We have a WEBEAR it is the client.Request comes to WEBEAR.
2. We have ServiceEAR, it is service side Request goes from client to this service.
This is developed using SOAP webservice (JAX-WS).

Now at the time of login I am taking location value from the user and save it to the session, since session is available only in client side and I passing  location in every service request. I want I pass location in service side at once at the time of login when session starts and it remains throughout the session I don't need to pass the location again and again with every service request.

Please suggest some solution/framework/architecture.